# When shutting down, how to re-open apps on their respective desktops?

Tags: macos, shutdown

I work with 4 desktops, and every time I shutdown my machine, I tell it to re-open all windows on next boot.

The problem is, with the exception of [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/), they all re-open on the first desktop (probably because it's the one showing by default).

I would like for every window to open in the desktop it was when I shut down the machine last time. This should be possible as **iTerm2** always open on the desktop it was shutdown in.

How do I do this?

The apps I'm having this issue are

- Google Chrome: I have at least 1 window (with multiple tabs) on each desktop.
- PHPStorm: I have 1 window on desktop number 3

Comment: FWIW this isn't standard behaviour. Apps *should* go back to the desktops that they were in before the shutdown. Is it apps like Photoshop which don't use the standard OS X windowing? Do first-party apps like Safari obey?

Comment: I've found apps will only open to specific Spaces if they are already locked to that Space - otherwise they open to whichever is frontmost as they launch, which isn't always 1, if other apps are already opening on specific Spaces. … so I guess the answer is "set them to specific spaces'… [Photoshop behaves perfectly, here, btw… though MRD only manages to get its 'list of locations' screen right, then every Remote session opens on the right space but the wrong screen]

Comment: @grgarside check out my edit

Comment: Re edit: You can't force it to open an app on more than one Space [unless there's some 3rd party util to do that] You can't even force 2 instances of an app to open on more than one space, as they both get 'remembered' on whichever as used last.

Answer (score 1):

If apps don't obey OS X's default windowing (which is to put apps back where they were before you logged out), then you can lock them to specific desktops which forces them to obey:

Right-click on the app in the Dock, then choose Options → This Desktop.

[image]